# Monkey-patching Rails: BigDecimal output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

I'm storing money values in my DB as the Decimal type, and am unhappy with the fact that they get mapped into BigDecimal in rails and so are printed using scientific notation. (Yes, I probably should have stored integer cents instead.)

1. The console command `MyModel.first` outputs decimal prices like regular floats after this monkey-patch:

   ```
   class BigDecimal
     def inspect
       to_s
     end
   end
   ```
2. However, the console command `puts MyModel.first.to_yaml` does not output decimal prices as regular floats after this monkey-patch:

   ```
   class BigDecimal
     def to_yaml
       to_s
     end
   end
   ```
3. ... but it does what I'd expect with `puts BigDecimal.new(1).to_yaml`.

I'm not super comfortable looking through the ruby and rails source repositories, but I've tried and couldn't find where the output formatting is happening in the second case above.

Where should I be looking? What am I missing?

Comment: Does this seem like a lot of work to avoid switching to an integer field?

Comment: @BradWerth Well, the first two were a snap, and way easier than switching to an integer field (and tracking down all every other change which that requires). I'm fine with where I'm at now with my `inspect` and `to_yaml` monkey patches, but it would be _nice_ if there was a quick and easy answer for part 2. Plus I thought I might learn something! :-) At some point I'm sure we'll refactor to an integer field, but now is unfortunately not the time for that.